# How can I added @readonly = readonly to an existing additionalViewData property?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm doing something like this:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DimensionEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> a_html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> a_expression, DimensionLock a_lock, object a_additionalViewData)
{
    var dictionary = new RouteValueDictionary(a_additionalViewData);

    if (a_lock.IsLocked)
    {
        object htmlAttributes;
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue("htmlAttributes", out htmlAttributes))
        {
            var htmlAttributesDict = new RouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes);
            htmlAttributesDict["@readonly"] = "readonly";
            htmlAttributes = htmlAttributesDict;
        }
        else
        {
            htmlAttributes = new {@readonly = "readonly"};
        }

        dictionary["htmlAttributes"] = htmlAttributes;
    }

    return a_html.EditorFor(a_expression, dictionary);
}
```

This doesn't work because `RouteValueDictionary` object are not allowable values for `additionalViewData` in the `EditorFor` extension method. I want to set readonly on the rendered text box if `a_lock.IsLocked` is true.

**Updates**:

I have tried the following just to see if `ViewDataDictionary` would work. It does not.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DimensionEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> a_html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> a_expression, DimensionLock a_lock, object a_additionalViewData)
{
    var dictionary = new ViewDataDictionary();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in new RouteValueDictionary(a_additionalViewData))
        dictionary.Add(pair.Key, pair.Value);

    return a_html.EditorFor(a_expression, dictionary);
}
```

Comment: `a_html.EditorFor(a_expression, new { htmlAttributes = htmlAttributes })` seems correct, no?

Comment: First, can htmlAttributes be a `RouteValueDictionary`? Second, that would eliminate any other values that might be on `a_additionalViewData`. I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly elegant, but if all you need is for the object to be a `ViewDataDictionary` instead of a `RouteValueDictionary`. You could always do:

```
var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary();
foreach (var key in dictionary.Keys)
{
    viewData[key] = dictionary[key];
}
```

Comment: It would seem that `ViewDataDictionary` accepts an object in its constructor. I could probably just pass in `additionalViewData` directly. I'll have to try this tomorrow at work. Thanks.

Comment: It takes an object but it only works with an anonymous object, not just any old type you care to throw at it.

Comment: My `a_additionalViewData` is an anonymous object. I do this with `RouteValueDictionary` in my code up there. ^

Comment: As mentioned in my updates. This didn't work even without the `IsLocked` logic.